# Can not make an element stick

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make an element stick to the top of my webpage while scrolling down, basically I am in my CSS trying to use

```
.stick-to-top {background-color:yellow; position: -webkit-sticky;  position: sticky;  top: 0;}
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="stick-to-top">
Can not make this text stick<br>
Can not make this text stick<br>
Can not make this text stick<br>
Can not make this text stick<br>
Can not make this text stick<br>
Can not make this text stick<br>
Can not make this text stick<br>
</div>
<div style="background-color:red; position: -webkit-sticky;  position: sticky;  top: 250px;">
Can not make this text stick<br>
Can not make this text stick<br>
Can not make this text stick<br>
Can not make this text stick<br>
Can not make this text stick<br>
Can not make this text stick<br>
Can not make this text stick<br>
</div>
<br><hr><br><br><hr><br><br><hr><br><br><hr><br><br><hr><br><br><hr><br><br><hr><br><br><hr><br><br><hr><br><br><hr>
<br><hr><br><br><hr><br><br><hr><br><br><hr><br><br><hr><br><br><hr><br><br><hr><br><br><hr><br><br><hr><br><br><hr>
<br><hr><br><br><hr><br><br><hr><br><br><hr><br><br><hr><br><br><hr><br><br><hr><br><br><hr><br><br><hr><br><br><hr>
<br><hr><br><br><hr><br><br><hr><br><br><hr><br><br><hr><br><br><hr><br><br><hr><br><br><hr><br><br><hr><br><br><hr>
END of page
```

It works in https://codepen.io/pen/

I have a lot of styles already on my webpage of course, and if I on the first div
Right Click --> Inspect>Copy>Copy Styles gives me this:

```
    line-height: 28px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #111111;
    font-family: 'Roboto',helvetica,arial,sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background-color: yellow;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
```

Since I think something else on my webpage interferes, I have tried clearing div with { all: revert;}, { all: none;} and {all: unset;} but nothing works. I do not know have to further investigate this.

Comment: The code should be working fine! Maybe the `position: sticky;` is being overwritten later on in the css file?

Answer (score -1):

Everything seems fine in your code. It should work. If you think that other styles has been overriding your code then you can try using "!important" in your css.

example:

```
position: sticky !important;
```

so that other style won't be able to override your code.

Or another thing you can try is use position: fixed; rather than position : sticky; but while using this you have to put margin-top to the first element after fixed-top element like I have used in below code.

```css
.stick-to-top {
  background-color:yellow; 
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

.first-element {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="stick-to-top">
fixed top
</div>

<div class="first-element" >
  first element after fixed top
</div>
<br><hr><br><br><hr><br><br><hr><br><br><hr><br><br><hr><br><br><hr><br><br><hr><br><br><hr><br><br><hr><br><br><hr>
<br><hr><br><br><hr><br><br><hr><br><br><hr><br><br><hr><br><br><hr><br><br><hr><br><br><hr><br><br><hr><br><br><hr>
<br><hr><br><br><hr><br><br><hr><br><br><hr><br><br><hr><br><br><hr><br><br><hr><br><br><hr><br><br><hr><br><br><hr>
<br><hr><br><br><hr><br><br><hr><br><br><hr><br><br><hr><br><br><hr><br><br><hr><br><br><hr><br><br><hr><br><br><hr>
END of page
```

Comment: position: sticky !important; does not work. position: fixed; seems to work, I just have to try it out and adjust the first element...

Comment: The problem is that the element goes outside screen on right side when position is not relative...you can see that the yellow box does not have margin on right side.

Comment: That's because the body element by default has an 8px margin on all sides. when the fixed top element got position: fixed and width: 100% It does not take the width of the body. To fix that you can add {left:0, margin:8px} to the .stick-to-top class but I guess this should not be the right approach because when you do this and when the page is scrollable the body element adjust itself according to the right side scroll bar but fixed top element does not.